# How can I call computed function from JavaScript defined in another computed function with Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this computed function defined in a standalone Vue component

```
watchForCustomer() {
  this.customerId = window.meta.page.customerId
  if(this.customerId) {
    $(document).on("click", function(element) {
      let checkout = ['checkout'].includes(element.currentTarget.activeElement.name)
      if(checkout) {
        let checkoutForm = ['checkout', 'cart'].includes(element.currentTarget.activeElement.form.action.split('/').at(-1))
        if(checkoutForm) {
          getCustomerCredit()
        }
      }
    })
  }
},
```

The problem is that `getCustomerCredit()` is not getting called.

I've tried to define it as:
`this.getCustomerCredit`
`getCustomerCredit()`
`app.$options.getCustomerCredit()`

and I get either that the function is not defined or it simply doesn't call it.

So how can I call this `getcustomerCredit` inside the `document` on click event?

For completeness this is all my code:

```
Vue.component('editable-text', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      message: "Yep, working",
      url: 'https://xxx',
      customerId: '',
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.watchForCustomer
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>Message is: {{ message }}</p>
      <input 
        v-model="message" 
        placeholder="edit me"
        :style="style"
        ></input>
    </div>`,
  computed: {
    style() {
      return {
        position: 'fixed',
        top: '100px',
        right: '30px',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        transition: 'all .4s',
        fontSize: '10px',
        color: '#000',
        border: 'none',
        background: 'hsla(0,0%,100%,.9098039215686274)',
        borderRadius: '10px',
        boxShadow: '0 0 0 2.5px #f2f2f2!important',
        width: '71px',
        height: 'auto',
        display: 'block',
        padding: '9px!important',
      }
    },
    watchForCustomer() {
      this.customerId = window.meta.page.customerId
      if(this.customerId) {
        $(document).on("click", function(element) {
          let checkout = ['checkout'].includes(element.currentTarget.activeElement.name)
          if(checkout) {
            let checkoutForm = ['checkout', 'cart'].includes(element.currentTarget.activeElement.form.action.split('/').at(-1))
            if(checkoutForm) {
              let me = Vue
              debugger
              getCustomerCredit()
            }
          }
        })
      }
    },
    async getCustomerCredit() {
      debugger
      let response = await axios.post(`${this.url}/app_proxy/customer`, { shopify_customer_id: this.customerId })
      debugger
    },
  },
  methods: {
    
  },
})

new Vue({ el: '#components-demo' })
```

Answer (score 1):

The source of your problem is because the below line, when you use the `function` keyword it changes what `this` refers to, i.e. `this` now refers to the context of the click.

```
$(document).on("click", function(element) {
```

You can fix this problem by using an arrow function so

```
$(document).on("click", element =>
```

You're also misusing `computed`,

`style` should be a data property because it has nothing reactive.

`watchForCustomer` should be moved to the `methods` section

`getCustomerCredit` should be moved to the `methods` section

Comment: I guess you meant "should be a method"

Comment: @EstusFlask I largely consider them to be same thing, but yes, I've updated my answer to be clearer as they were already functions but should be in the methods part of the Vue instance.

Answer (score 0):

Pow!! Got it. You need to use a hash rocket in the js function. So instead of this:

```
watchForCustomer() {
  this.customerId = window.meta.page.customerId
  if(this.customerId) {
    $(document).on("click", function(element) {
      let checkout = ['checkout'].includes(element.currentTarget.activeElement.name)
      if(checkout) {
        let checkoutForm = ['checkout', 'cart'].includes(element.currentTarget.activeElement.form.action.split('/').at(-1))
        if(checkoutForm) {
          let me = Vue
          debugger
          getCustomerCredit()
        }
      }
    })
  }
},
```

Do this and now you are able to access everything in Vue inside of the js function

```
watchForCustomer() {
  this.customerId = window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta.page.customerId
  if(this.customerId) {
    $(document).on(("click"), element => {
      let checkout = ['checkout'].includes(element.currentTarget.activeElement.name)
      if(checkout) {
        let checkoutForm = ['checkout', 'cart'].includes(element.currentTarget.activeElement.form.action.split('/').at(-1))
        if(checkoutForm) {
          this.getCustomerCredit
        }
      }
    })
  }
},
```

Comment: "hash rocket" is a term from Ruby. In JavaScript, it's called [*arrow function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (or colloquially *fat arrow*).